# Wait for all the HTML to PDF conversion before exporting as pdf

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to export graphs from HTML to pdf using html2canvas library. I am first taking all the divs using a for loop and generating corresponding image for them, and once all the conversion is done, I am calling `doc.save("file.pdf");` function to save it. However, I have to call doc.save() function inside a timeout after the for loop is done, since  `html2canvas('div_id').then()` which is responsible to converting html to images, is returning a promise and converting the html to image asynchronously. Is there a way where I can use promise and not setTimeout method. I am not able to come up with a solution using promise.

```
exportGraphonClick() {
   var metrics  = ["1", "2", "3","4","5","6"];
   var pageCount;
   var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm"); 

    // loop
    metrics.map((key,index) =>{
      let id_val = `graph-id-${index}`; // creating IDs
      const input = document.getElementById(id_val);

      // html to pdf
      html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/JPEG');
        var width  = 300;
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 40, width, 100);
        doc.addPage();
        pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
      });
    })  

     // saving pdf  
      setTimeout(()=> {
      doc.save("file.pdf");
    },2000)

}
```

Comment: call a method from "html2canvas.then"(where u r adding doc.addPage). In function write doc.save("file.pdf");

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI, Would you give an example?

Comment: @robbannn answer is good it works. Instead of going with promises we can acheive it with normal logic as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the function used in `map` `async`, and `await` the call to `html2canvas`. This will return an array of unresolved Promises. `Promise.all()` returns a new `Promise` that will resolve when all provided promises resolve.

```
metrics = metrics.map(async (key, index) => {
    let id_val = `graph-id-${index}`; // creating IDs
    const input = document.getElementById(id_val);

    // html to pdf
    let canvas = await html2canvas(input);
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/JPEG');
    let width  = 300;
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 40, width, 100);
    doc.addPage();
    pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();
})  

// saving pdf
Promise.all(metrics)
.then(() => doc.save("file.pdf"))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanx a lot buddy.